# Is it legal in CO to work as a Caregiver and not receive pay since Jan 31, 2024

Tags: united-states

I'm a Caregiver and my employer has not paid me for over 300 hours of work to include over time.The employer says once they get paid from the state for my clients homecare then I will receive backpay but there is no time when that is. I stopped getting paid on January 31,2024 but continue to work everyday totalling 67 hours per week. Is this legal?

Comment: Are you an employee or a contractor (do you get a W2 or a 1099 at the end of the year)?

Comment: This will probably be closed here as a request for specific legal advice.  It would be on topic on Workplace.

Comment: Sorry, we can't give legal advice here. Try Colorado legal Services  https://www.coloradolegalservices.org/node/327/contact-colorado-legal-services or Google for a labor lawyer in your area that gives free initial consultations.

Comment: Geez people, they are NOT asking for legal advice, they are asking what the law says about CO employers not paying employees!  On that note, it is legal for you you to work for free, but it may be illegal for an employer to withhold wages.  I would recommend you edit accordingly.

Comment: It is hard to make out who is who. Are the employer and the client the same person? Was there an agreement to be paid for the services at some hourly rate? What does it say about when payment is due? What is the relationship between you and the employer? Employee? Contractor? It isn't really clear what is happening.

Comment: @ohwilleke I think it's common for caregivers to work for an agency. So the agency would be the employer, the client is the person who they've been assigned to care for. The client pays the agency, the agency pays the caregiver. But whether the caregiver is an employee or independent contractor probably depends on the specific agency.

Comment: It also sounds like the client is on Medicare, which is why the agency is waiting for payment from the state rather than the client.

Comment: @Barmar Medicare is federal. So if they are waiting on the state it is more likely to be Medicaid.

Comment: @ohwilleke Thanks, I can never remember which is which (I'm not eligible for either, although I occasionally get robocalls offering Medicare assistance).

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the slightly wrong question. As I understand the law in CO, USA:

- Is it legal to work without being paid?
  Usually yes. Nobody forces you to accept a wage.
- Is it legal not to pay contractually agreed wages?
  Usually no. Contracts are binding unless special circumstances allow one or both sides to get out. That would usually cause civil lawsuits.
- Is it legal to work 67 hours a week?
  Usually yes. CO has no maximum worktime.
- Should there be overtime payment for work in excess of 40 hours per week?
  Usually yes. Federal legislation applies.

And all those 'usually' mean you have to tell the specific details of your case to a lawyer, not random guys on the web.

Comment: No, worktime limits exist, such a in Germany 40 hours.

Comment: @Trish, I did read CO as Colorado.

Comment: The answer then would be a qualified it depends on local labor law, not a usually yes. Colorado says irs OK, but not all countries do.

Comment: @trish, i read "usually" to qualify the answer, meaning it depends on local labor laws.

Comment: @MichaelHall, usually was supposed to mean depending on circumstances, which we do not know (and should not know, for privacy). The employer may or may not have filed bankruptcy. The contract may or may not mention overtime.

Comment: @Trish, clarified.

Comment: Circumstances, jurisdiction, etc. whatever... My point was directed at Trish because overtime rules exist in the US too.  They may not be the same as Germany, but the wording of the answer already covers this, and allows for regional variation.  If she wants to answer specifically for Germany then answer for Germany!

Comment: The Colorado Wage Act (C.R.S. 8-4-101 et seq.) requires Colorado employers to pay employees their earned wages in a timely manner. But it isn't clear if the worker in this case is an employee within the scope of the Act or not. Colorado also has a criminal wage theft statute, but that again depends upon the nature of the relationship as an employee or as a contractor. If the workers is a contractor, Colorado law has recognized the validity of pay when paid clauses under many circumstances for non-employees.